# Someone borrowed my phone and Im scared its hacked

Tags: mobile, monitoring, spyware, identity-theft, crime

I am from Australia and I use a iPhone 4.

Today, a young guy asked to borrow my phone, since he was out of credit and since I was trying to be a good samaritan, let him borrow my phone (also we were at a well surveillance area). He told me that he was meeting his friend and he just arrived. Did not think much of it at the time, and I was with another girlfriend so we just kept talking whilst he borrowed my phone.

He was only using it for about a minute or two but after we walked away, I decided to check my call log, and saw that he dialled two numbers. Getting abit suspicious, because It didn't seem like was looking at his phone to find the contacts but more like he remembered the numbers in his head.

So I come home, accidentally (honestly) pocket dialled one of the two numbers for about two rings until I pressed the end call button. 20 minutes later, my phone rings saying "NO CALLER ID" and i pick up because I was pretty sure it was one of the two numbers. He asked me who it was, and I asked if it was the guy that borrowed my phone and he said yes it was, In which i replied , with an apology and that i accidentally pocket dialled him. then I think he thanked me for borrowing my phone and then asked me to coffee in which I replied with a no and we hung up.

I am suspicious because when he borrowed my phone, he said he was calling a friend, but it was him on the line when he called me back. Also I then checked my call logs more closely both the numbers dialled says "canceled" next to them, which means the calls didn't go through, because if it went through it would have said how long the duration of the call went on for.

So should I be paranoid? or is it just some guy thats a bit weird and wanted my number without having to ask for it? Also what I should do if my phone is being tapped/tracked/monitored/spied on. thanks.

Comment: I have NO clue how this could possibly be an IT Security question.

Comment: HE WAS TOO SHY TO ASK FOR YOUR NUMBER!

Comment: @schroeder is probably right. He called himself from your phone so he could get your number. Kinda pathetic.

Comment: iphones are the bane of existence of ANY malicious code. so don't think two calls will make your phone bad. and yeah, you're a bit paranoid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If someone asks to borrow your phone to make a call, what could they do?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25772/if-someone-asks-to-borrow-your-phone-to-make-a-call-what-could-they-do)

Comment: Doesn't belong on this forum

Answer (score 3):

I think here is not the place to ask this kind of question.

Anyway, I don't think it is possible to hack a phone with a couple calls (yet). Should you notice any suspicious activity in your phone bill you can ask for help in your telephone company. In case your phone behaviour is odd, you can factory reset the device, which should erase anything that might have happened.

Comment: well not *technically* true - someone could subscribe you to a premium telephone service that charge you for things like "A joke a day" text messages by dialing or texting a specific number. While it's debatable whether or not this is "hacking" a phone, it would be an unwanted result of potentially lending your phone to someone (and probably quite unlikely that this is the case)